# [Plugin leenk.me]modify get_the_title

Tags: permalinks, facebook, title, excerpt

I use a plugin called leenk.me to post messages to Facebook based on my posts. One of the custom fields is %TITLE%, which posts the title of my post and the link to my post.

```
if ( false === $post_title )
    $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );
```

The way I currently have my WP set up, my excerpt is a link. I want to modify the get_the_title function so that instead of getting the title and link (ID) to my post, it gets the title and the link to the excerpt.

```
function get_the_title( $post = 0 ) {
  $post = get_post( $post );

  $title = isset( $post->post_title ) ? $post->post_title : '';
  $id = isset( $post->ID) ? $post->ID : 0;

  if ( ! is_admin() ) {
    if ( ! empty( $post->post_password ) ) {
        $protected_title_format = apply_filters( 'protected_title_format', __( 'Protected: %s' ) );
        $title = sprintf( $protected_title_format, $title );
    } else if ( isset( $post->post_status ) && 'private' == $post->post_status ) {
        $private_title_format = apply_filters( 'private_title_format', __( 'Private: %s' ) );
        $title = sprintf( $private_title_format, $title );
    }
  }

  return apply_filters( 'the_title', $title, $id );
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "link to the excerpt"?

Answer (score 0):

"I want to modify the get_the_title function" -- Do you mean you want to modify WordPress's `get_the_title()`, or simply modify what it returns?  If the former, I must *strongly* advise against it. You shouldn't hack core files in WordPress.  If you want to modify what it returns, use the [`the_title` filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title).

Comment: so should I change it to if ( false === $post_title )
    $post_title = the_title( $post_id ); ? How can I change the_title to pull the_excerpt instead of the shortlink it normally grabs?

Comment: What does the relevant code from your leenk.me plugin look like?  (Please add it to your question, since it can be formatted nicely in there.)